# What does posts% mean under top tags?

Tags: support

In the new profile page, for my top tag under top tags, I see this:

[image]

The score and post count I understand. What does the post *percent* mean? The tooltip doesn't give any relevant information.

Comment: The percentage of your posts that have been posted in this tag.

Comment: SE really likes putting mouseover explanations in various elements.  One of those 'if you didn't know they always do this...' things.

Comment: @Kendra Gotcha! So you're saying I should branch out from C++ a bit...

Comment: @Barry, if it's what you're good at, and your gold badge says that probably you are, you should see if there's any new concept you can learn in it. If not, it's always good to learn new things. :) If you decide to branch out, maybe tackle a technology that you don't know much about and isn't too similar to C++ so you learn more, and make yourself more valuable overall as a programmer.

Comment: I'm probably just dense, but where on the profile did you find the "top tags"? I can't find this anywhere on my profile page.

Comment: @RetoKoradi http://stackoverflow.com/users/3530129/reto-koradi

Comment: @Barry Yes, that's my profile page, where I was looking for this. But I still don't see a "top tags" list with these statistics. I tried "View More" in the "Tags" section of the "Summary" tab, as well as the "tags" tab.

Comment: @GrantWinney Oh, thanks! Indeed, I was only checking the Activity page.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It means that n% of your posts have been posted in that specific tag.

We can check this with a little math. At this point in time, you have 680 answers and 71 questions, for a total of 751 posts.

Of those, 708 have been posted in [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). 708/751 comes out to ~.942, or 94%.

We can cross-check this by looking at another user's stats. For this one, we'll use my meta stats.

At the time of writing, I have 25 posts on meta, this one included. My top tag is [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) with a 64 post%. With 16 posts in that tag, it comes out to be 16/25, or .64 (64%) on the dot.

Comment: Note that the total posts can be more than 100% as a result of questions being tagged with more than one tag.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm afraid you've confused me. Do you mean that the total posts % can be more than 100%? Because that makes complete sense and is supported by your statement of multiple tags. As it's worded now, it sounds like you're saying that one single tag can have more than 100% of your posts.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing wording. I meant that of your set of tags, it is possible that the posts % totals more than 100 from all of them together. Individually, there should be no way to have more than 100% barring some sort of bug.

Comment: This profile element definitely needs a different tool tip.