# "%" symbol appearing in the new user profile page

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

My activity page:

[image]

What does the "%" symbol mean in this context? Why only the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag have it in this case?

Hovering on it doesn't really help, couldn't find the answer in the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1).

**EDIT**

---

I now know what the symbol is for, but I think it should be more descriptive when hovering on it. It's not documented anywhere and it's not that understandable.

Comment: I believe it chose java because that's your top tag, and 75% of all your posts are tagged java.

Comment: I think it should be described somewhere, hovering on it displays exactly the same content as "POSTS". Thanks.

Comment: Agreed, the title text is not easy to decipher and it's not that relevant.

Comment: This was actually asked yesterday: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290358/what-does-posts-mean-under-top-tags That said, I agree they could at the very least describe it somewhere.